# What is the difference between verb phrase and verb like make a wish and wish, make a call and call?

Tags: word-usage, meaning, phrase-meaning

I wanna know the difference between verb phrase and verb itself like in make a call and call, and  make a wish and wish.

1. make a wish, wish
2. make a call, call

What is the difference between two words in the same number(1 and 2)?
Please help me.

Comment: You should write '_I want to_', not 'I wanna'.

Answer (score 3):

There is not always a difference.

In many cases, the two forms are interchangeable; but there is often a syntactic difference, not a difference in meaning.

Both *call* and *wish* are normally transitive: they mostly require an object to be expressed, even if it is indefinite. But the nouns *call* and *wish* can be used without an object.

So:

> I'll call Mr Jones when I get back.

or

> I'll call somebody when I get back.

or

> I'll make a call when I get back.

but not

> *I'll call when I get back.

unless the person they will call has already been established in the conversation.

Similarly

> He wished for success in the competition..

or

> He wished for something.

or

> He made a wish.

but not normally

> *He wished.

Comment: Also, you can _wish for_ something, meaning that you would like it to happen, but _making a wish_ is usually done in special circumstances (dropping a coin in a 'wishing well', or blowing out the candles on your birthday cake, for example), which are traditionally supposed to help that wish to come true.